# How do you programmatically switch the top bar color? not just once but multiple times when the app is running

Tags: android, colors, youtube, styles

On the youtube app when you go to someone's channel the top bar changes color.

It goes from red to some other color

How do they get it to change color multiple times throughout the app? What is the code behind it? I would like to do a similar thing in my android app.

Comment: Does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

**Dynamically**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

**Styles**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item> <!-- statusbar color -->
    </style>

    <style name="RecyclerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_recycler</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark_recycler</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.eugene.eugenehoranresume"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.RecyclerExample"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/RecyclerTheme">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```